# Undetected Chromedriver, AttributeError: 'ChromeOptions' object has no attribute 'headless'

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I'm getting an error when I run a Python Selenium script to open a webpage. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling selenium, chromeautoinstaller, and undetected chromedriver. I also tried adding `option.add_argument('--headless')`. None of these were successful and the error remained the same.

Here is my code:

```py
    def driverInit():
        option = uc.ChromeOptions()
        option.add_argument("--log-level=3")
    
        prefs = {"credentials_enable_service": False,
                 "profile.password_manager_enabled": False,
                 "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2
                 }
        option.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
        driverr = uc.Chrome(options=option)
        return driverr
    
    def driverInitBuffMarket():
        option = uc.ChromeOptions()
        option.add_argument(
             rf'--user-data-dir=C:\Users\{os.getlogin()}\AppData\Local\Google\ChromeBuff\User Data')  # e.g. C:\Users\You\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
        option.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Default')
        driverr = uc.Chrome(options=option)
        return driver
```

The error occurs in the second-to-last line, `driverr = uc.Chrome(options=option)`

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kumpd\OneDrive\Desktop\All Market Bots\BuffMarket Purchase Bot Testing\main.py", line 266, in <module>
    start_buy_monitoring()
  File "C:\Users\kumpd\OneDrive\Desktop\All Market Bots\BuffMarket Purchase Bot Testing\main.py", line 207, in start_buy_monitoring
    driverBuffMarket = driverInitBuffMarket()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kumpd\OneDrive\Desktop\All Market Bots\BuffMarket Purchase Bot Testing\main.py", line 42, in driverInitBuffMarket
    driverr = uc.Chrome(options=option)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kumpd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 398, in __init__
    if headless or options.headless:
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'ChromeOptions' object has no attribute 'headless'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of today, undetected-chromedriver is still using `options.headless` in their code.

That's a problem due to this change in `selenium` `4.13.0` that was just released:

```
* remove deprecated headless methods
```

Here are some alternatives:

- Downgrade to an earlier selenium version until fixed.
- Use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase)'s [UC Mode](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/issues/2000) (a modified fork of undetected-chromedriver):

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver
import time

driver = Driver(uc=True)
driver.get("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
time.sleep(6)
driver.quit()
```

Here's another, more advanced example with retries and clicks (using the `SB()` manager):

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True) as sb:
    sb.driver.get("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
    sb.sleep(2)
    if not sb.is_text_visible("OH YEAH, you passed!", "h1"):
        sb.get_new_driver(undetectable=True)
        sb.driver.get("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
        sb.sleep(2)
    if not sb.is_text_visible("OH YEAH, you passed!", "h1"):
        if sb.is_element_visible('iframe[src*="challenge"]'):
            with sb.frame_switch('iframe[src*="challenge"]'):
                sb.click("span.mark")
                sb.sleep(4)
    sb.activate_demo_mode()
    sb.assert_text("OH YEAH, you passed!", "h1", timeout=3)
```

(This is mainly what I wrote here: https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/1584#issuecomment-1737963363)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue what I did was I went back to my prior requirements what you need to do is as following
elaborating on details is the current undetected chrome driver isn't compatible with selenium as the undetected chrome drive uses headless and the selenium version doesn't use that so what we do is that we redo to the most stable verion of selenium and its support which was working priorly and that could be done by the method that I have mentioned that you create a new enviornment and then install these stable library dependencies which wouldn't then lead to the errors you were facing earlier
#create new virtual enviornment
python -m venv env
#activate the env
env/scripts/activate
#install requirements.txt
pip install -r requirements.txt
I have attached the requirements file in this link [File](https://github.com/AffanAhmedUsmani/Issue-Resolution/blob/main/requirements.txt)

Comment: it is the version problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).