# Undetectedchromedriver not open

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

Why it isnt working

```
from selenium import webdriver
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

if __name__ =='__main__':
    options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get('https://nowsecure.nl')
    driver.save_screenshot('nowsecure.png')
```

The code executes and the screenshot is taken and saved but de webpage window doesn't open, even taking out the screenshot code line the webpage doesn't open so i can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Comment this line:

```py
# options.add_argument("--headless")
```

Comment: When i comment this line the code doesnt work with this error:  __init__
    if headless or options.headless:
AttributeError: 'ChromeOptions' object has no attribute 'headless'

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with running headless using undetected chromedriver. You can take a look at [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77191221/undetected-chromedriver-attributeerror-chromeoptions-object-has-no-attribute).

- As an alternative use [seleniumbase](https://seleniumbase.io/help_docs/install/):

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver # pip install seleniumbase
import time

driver = Driver(uc=True)
driver.get('https://nowsecure.nl')
time.sleep(6)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem adding setting headless by another way and the closing using timesleep

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import time


options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = False
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://nowsecure.nl")
time.sleep(100)
```